# My nav menu is over website content in mobile view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a nav menu on my website and when I change resolution to mobile to see if it's responsive or not, the menu goes over the website content, how can I resolve it?
Here is a screenshot of how it is now.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWg5z.png)
**Here is the HTML Code**

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/navbar.css" />
    <title>Navigation bar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div id="brand"><a href="main.php">Cactus Soup</a></div>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/home">Top Filmes</a></li>
          <li><a href="/products">Top Seris</a></li>
          <li><a href="/about">Sobre nos</a></li>
          <li id="login"><a href="/login" >Login</a></li>
          <li id="signup"><a href="/signup">Registar</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <div id="hamburger-icon" onclick="toggleMobileMenu(this)">
        <div class="bar1"></div>
        <div class="bar2"></div>
        <div class="bar3"></div>
        <ul class="mobile-menu">
          <li><a href="/home">Top Filmes</a></li>
          <li><a href="/products">Top Seris</a></li>
          <li><a href="/about">Sobre Nos</a></li>
          <li id="login"><a href="/login" >Login</a></li>
          <li id="signup"><a href="/signup">Registar</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </header>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    asjjajjgassssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssa
  </body>
</html>
```

**Here is the CSS code**

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;700&display=swap");

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #353836;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  padding: 0 20px;
  background-color: #1d1f1d;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#brand {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#brand a {
  color: #09c372;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

ul a {
  color: white;
}

ul li {
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

ul li:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#login,
#signup {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
}

#login {
  border: 1px solid #498afb;
}

#signup {
  border: 1px solid #ff3860;
}

#signup a {
  color: #ff3860;
}

#login a {
  color: #498afb;
}

#hamburger-icon {
  margin: auto 0;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hamburger-icon div {
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.open .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-6px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-6px, 6px);
}

.open .bar2 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.open .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-6px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-6px, -8px);
}

.open .mobile-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.mobile-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.mobile-menu li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  header nav {
    display: none;
  }

  #hamburger-icon {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

**Here is the JS code**

```
function toggleMobileMenu(menu) {
    menu.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

I'll be really grateful if someone help me!

Comment: how should it look

Answer (score 0):

You should use @media, and add some padding or margin depending on what you need.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
}
```

You can watch here for more information: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem you have right now happens when the Menu is open and when you change the resolution your menu is visible by default. You need to add `resize` eventListener to close the menu if it's open and the screen size got bigger than `600`. Here is an example:

```
const menu = document.getElementById("hamburger-icon");

window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
    // If window smaller than 600 || menu doesn't have an
    // open state then do nothing
    if (window.innerWidth <= 600 || !menu.classList.contains("open"))
        return;

    // Remvoe open class otherwise
    menu.classList.remove("open");
});
```